# teachers'' homes vs teachers homes

Tags: grammar

https://www.lingq.com/lesson/lesson-21-the-right-to-education-431416/

**In ancient Greece from around three thousand to two thousand years ago students were educated in their teachers'' homes.**

What is the meaning of the sign  ***''***  in the above context? isn't that sign redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The genitive rule states that the apostrophe is before the "s" unless the word itself would end in s either because it is plural or because it ends naturally in s.

Therefore, it is right that the apostrophe follows "teachers", however the 2nd apostrophe is redundant.  My guess is that it is simply a typo.  :)